# How to display an image from the internet in android?

Tags: android

How can I display image in an `ImageView` in android from a URL (from the internet)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the method [setImageDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView;

URL url = new URL(address);
InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
iv.setImageDrawable(d)
```

[2014-12-16] Edit: Using Picasso, makes your life much simplier

```
String url = "http://i.imgur.com/bIRGzVO.jpg";
ImageView iv = new ImageView;

Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(iv);
//Picasso.with(context).load(url).centerCrop().fit().into(iv);
```

Comment: thanks alot, but the application became very slow in running ??!

Comment: The application became very slow in running, because most probably you are running this code on main thread. Move the code in background thread, to speed up the app

Comment: This no longer works without an asynch task. Now if you tried this from an activity or fragment you would get... Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: i got error on Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); When d is returning null value. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use the [setImageUri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29) method. The URI can be built using [Uri.parse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: sorry for this question , but how can i make URI object for my link string ??

Comment: added this detail in my answer

Answer (score 1):

first u need to hit image url and store the server Data as byte array, then u need to convert these byte data into Bitmap image.. Here is the code

```
                String myfeed="http://174.136.1.35/dev/atmsearch/visa.jpg";

                try{

                    URL url=new URL(myfeed);
                    URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("METHOD", "POST");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-from-urlencoded");

                    HttpURLConnection httpConnection=(HttpURLConnection)connection;

                    int responsecode=httpConnection.getResponseCode();

                    if(responsecode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                        InputStream in=((URLConnection)httpConnection).getInputStream();
                        int len=0;
                        Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);



                        System.out.println(b.toString());


                        byte[] data1=new byte[1024];

                        while(-1!=(len=in.read(data1))){
                            System.out.println("--input stream--");
                            datafromserver.append(new String(data1,0,len));

                        }
                        //System.out.println(datafromserver);
                    }

                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Error...."+e);
                    //Toast.makeText(context, text, duration)

                }
```

// Now set the bitmap image in image view
imageview.setImageBitmap(b);

Comment: datafromserver is string builder.. if u don't use u will also get ur image in variable b. try to put b in ur image view.

Answer (score 0):

First hit the image link,then you will get the image as byte array.Now just decode the byte array to bitmap image.Lets take a look:

```
package Image.Read.a;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class Connecetion1
{
 public void setNetwork()
 {
    try
    {

        URL url = new URL("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_9UYLMDqrnnE/S4UgSrTt8LI/AAAAAAAADxI/drlWsmQ8HW0/s400/sachin_tendulkar_double_century.jpg");

        URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();

        HttpURLConnection HCon=(HttpURLConnection)connection;

        int ResCode=HCon.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("Responce Code is = "+ResCode);


        if(ResCode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {

        InputStream ins=((URLConnection)HCon).getInputStream();   

              Data.StoreImg=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins);


        }

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
        {

          e.printStackTrace();
         }

 }
```

}

You can get the full tutorial from http://www.androidcookers.blogspot.com/2011/06/retrieve-image-from-internet.html