# Android - How can I display an image from a URL?

Tags: android

I have an ImageView and all I need to do is display an image from the intetrnet when the app loads. Is there a very simple way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display image from internet in android ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223472/how-to-display-image-from-internet-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet( url);

HttpResponse response = client.execute( get );
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( response.getEntity().getContent() );
```

Comment: client.execute( get ); gets underlined immediately and the error says "Unhandled exception type ClientProtocolException"

Comment: So handle the exception type...surround it in a try/catch

Comment: What error? The error you mentioned earlier was related to not catching a possible exception that would be thrown. You are catching the exception now.

Comment: The error i was getting before was at design time, before the app even runs. Now when it runs i get "the app has stopped unexpectedly"

Comment: i needed to add the internet permission in the manifest. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`ImageView.setImageURI` does not seem to work for internet resources, so you should read the bitmap yourself.

```
InputStream is = new URL("http://example.com/myimage.jpg").openStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
is.close(); 
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But this loads the image on the UI thread, which can cause hiccups. It is preferable to do it in a different thread, for example using:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            return loadBitmap(params[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("imagetask", "error loading bitmap", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected Bitmap loadBitmap(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new URL(urlSpec).openStream();
        try {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        } 
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}.execute("http://example.com/myimage.jpg");
```

Comment: I have this code running without error but the image is never displayed. The imageview is empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JJD, not really... is there an exception thrown somewhere and/or visible in LogCat? I'll add some code for the exception handling, I left that out.

Comment: i needed to add the internet permission in the manifest. thanks!