# waIISHost does not restart emulated local azure

Tags: azure

I'm working through "Windows Azure Step by Step", an MSPRESS book. On page 55, the author suggests upping the number of instances in the web role to 5, then running the project. He invites the reader to kill WaIISHost instances.

He suggests there should be 10 instances, despite saying that the instance count was set to 5. On my machine, there's only 5 instances of the WaIISHost.EXE processes. Am I wrong to think that the number of configured instances should be equal to the number of running processes, not double as the author says?

If I kill a process, it doesn't restart. In the Compute Emulator UI, the status changes to a question mark for that numbered instance, and I see spew in the UI for the killed instance that says it doesn't know its role anymore:

```
[fabric] Role state Destroyed
[fabric] Role state Unknown
[fabric] Role state Destroyed  
[fabric] Role state Unknown
```

Why doesn't the compute emulator restart a killed process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576676/how-to-parse-complex-json-file-in-android/13585531#13585531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I blogged about this a few weeks ago: [Controlling your instances in the Windows Azure Compute Emulator](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/controlling-your-instances-in-the-windows-azure-compute-emulator/). Try to run the application without debugger and kill an instance, that should fix the Destroyed/Unknown loop (the 1.8 sdk should work with the debugger though).

And there should  be only 1 **WaIISHost.exe** process per running instance. This means, spinning up 5 instances will start 5 **WaIISHost.exe** processes. Note that for each running instance you will also have an additional **WaHostBootstrapper.exe** process.

Answer (score -1):

Does your application works fine if only 5 instance in Azure compute emulator?

Double check that each Azure assembly your project is referencing has the copy to local property set to true.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't read the book, Marcondes. At this point, the application is trivial. Can you tell me where the "copy to local" property is in the Project Explorer window, and how it would affect this behaviour?