# Get unknow number of values in Jsonobject and set them into spinner for Android

Tags: android, json, string, parsing, spinner

I'm doing an application that need to receive an unknow number of names with they and a id.

I have solved the php and mysql part and this is what I receive into my app:

```
[{"id":"3","nombre":"Kaotik Sabadel"},{"id":"4","nombre":"Promotor Kaotik"}]
```

In the android part I start with this:

```
myJsonObj = new JSONObject(jodata);
```

and that's all I have.

And I want to set the names (nombre) into an spinner and when the user choose this name, get the value of his id...

Comment: Why do you put your json in an image!?

Comment: for json parsing look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576676/how-to-parse-complex-json-file-in-android/13576784#13576784

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom [`SpinnerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) which parses the [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) (and no [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)) and fills the data into your `Spinner`.

As a little hint how to parse the data use this code:

```
JSONArray data=new JSONArray(json);
for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject element=data.getJSONObject(i);
    int id=element.getInt("id");
    // ...
}
```

The part with the id may failes because it is a string and no integer just now I don't know if JSONObject can detect that the value can be casted to an int. If not use getString and parse it to a int.